# how to define a vector with fixed size?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

I want to define a vector of strings with a fixed size 3 in the multi-index table of smart contract. I search and tried different ways which I found for CPP vector like:

```
std::vector<string> abc(3);
```

But didn't worked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOSIO.CDT doesn't support `std::array` in function argument or field of multi_index struct. You can try my customized version of cdt, [eoscc](https://github.com/turnpike/eoscc) which supports `std::array`.

If you want to use official EOSIO.CDT, you had better use `std::vector`, but limit the number of items by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
std::array<string, 3> abc;
```

**UPDATE:**

`std::array` causes compilation segmentation fault

You can make your own array:

```
class MyFixedArray {
  int a[3];
public:
  auto begin() {...}
  auto end() {...}
  ....
};

struct [[eosio::table]] TableWithArray {
     MyFixedArray values;
...
```

I think it should work. Didn't test that though :)

Comment: If I use this and compile the smart contract. It generates: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Indeed. Didn't know about that, sorry.

Comment: If you stuck with this, consider using table/field through custom interface (adaptor).